# Dart で文字列を圧縮した文字列に変換する方法はないですか？

Tags: javascript

DartでWebページを作成しており、Webページ上の作業データをテキスト形式でダウンロードさせているのですが、
データの容量が数メガバイトととても大きくなってしまい困っております。
ダウンロードファイルをZIPで圧縮すると数十キロバイトまで下がるので圧縮したいです。
Javascritp のライブラリを使う方法は見つかりましたが、
Dart の機能で文字列を圧縮した文字列に変換する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 質問内容が曖昧に感じるのですが、ダウンロードさせるファイルを生のテキストファイルではなく、zip形式にしたいという趣旨でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2016/01/01
回答で書くようにと指摘があったので書き直します。

2015/12/30
＞Terryさん、holywiseさん
すみません。今更ですが解決できました。

```
List<int> compressed = GZIP.encode(UTF8.encode(yourText));
```

上記のコードはライブラリが見つからなかったので、そのまま実装はできませんでしたが、
参考にして下記のように実装したら希望通りに動きました。

```
GZipEncoder gzip = new GZipEncoder();
Utf8Encoder utf8 = new Utf8Encoder();
List<int> compressed = gzip.encode(utf8.convert(json));
String zipStr = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(compressed);
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to serve gzip-encoded html page - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672578/dart-how-to-serve-gzip-encoded-html-page) が参考になります。
HTTP/1.1の応答としてその文字列をクライアントに渡す場合は、`HttpServer.autoCompress`を`true`にしておけば相手がGZIP対応であれば自動的にGZIP圧縮されます。
単にある文字列をGZIP圧縮したバイト列に変換したいときは次のようになります：

```
List<int> compressed = GZIP.encode(UTF8.encode(yourText));
```

Comment: すみません、文字列を圧縮したバイト列を取得したいのではなく、
文字列を圧縮文字列に変換したいです。
Javascript で WebStorageにデータを保存するために、文字列を圧縮文字列にするライブラリがあったので、
Dartに標準で同じような機能がないかと思って質問しました。